# vmc instances appname 3 gives error: Unknown app '3'

Tags: cloud-foundry, vmc

I have installed Ruby and Gems and also installed VMC following the documentation on the cloudfoundry website. I could deploy a simple hello world application successfully. Several commands seem to work fine. However, few commands just fail and I have no clue why. 
When I run the following command:

vmc instances hellor 3

I get an error: Unknwon app '3'

When I just run:

vmc instances hellor
It retrieves the instance fine and displays it without any error. But, when I specify a number after that to increase the instances, it just seem to treat that number as an appname and gives me error. What could be the reason. I could not find anyone else facingup this issue on any of the forums. Any help on this will be highly appreciated. I am deploying on cloudfoundry.com

Answer (score 3):

The behavior of this command depends on the version of vmc you are using. You can see the version of vmc you are running with `vmc --version`.

With vmc version 0.3.x, the `instances` command works as you are expecting it to in your question. If you run `vmc help` with version 0.3.x, you will see this among other output:

```
instances <appname> <num|delta>              Scale the application instances up or down
```

With vmc version 0.4.x (also known as vmc-ng), the `instances` command works differently and the `scale` command is introduced, as Hitesh says. If you run `vmc help --all` with version 0.4.x, you will see this among other ouput:

```
instances APPS...           List an app's instances
scale [APP]                 Update the instances/memory limit for an application
```

Answer (score 1):

"vmc instances [APP]" is used to list the number of instances you have. To actually scale your application you can do "vmc scale [APP]" as shown below:

hghia@SEA-007~/workgalaxy/hello$ vmc scale hello

Instances> 3

1: 64M

2: 128M

3: 256M

4: 512M

5: 1G

6: 2G

Memory Limit> 64M

Scaling hello... OK

hghia@SEA-007~/workgalaxy/hello$ vmc instances hello

Getting instances for hello... OK

instance #0: running 
  started: 2012-12-10 03:41:39 PM

instance #1: running 
  started: 2012-12-10 03:46:56 PM

instance #2: running 
  started: 2012-12-10 03:46:56 PM

Thanks,
- Hitesh